# Expo notification crash app when app is in foreground -- TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'registration.listener.apply')

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications

Expo app crash when receive a notification and app in foreground
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'registration.listener.apply')

Followed this steps to implement: [text](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=performancemax&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIy9DmoNyS_wIVqw4GAB35rAQ4EAAYASAAEgI-EfD_BwE)

```
Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
    handleNotification: async () => ({
        shouldShowAlert: true,
        shouldPlaySound: true,
        shouldSetBadge: true
    })
})

useEffect(() => {
        registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => setExpoPushToken(token))

        notificationListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(notification => {
            setNotification(notification)
        })

        responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })

        return () => {
            Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(notificationListener.current)
            Notifications.removeNotificationSubscription(responseListener.current)
        }
    }, [])
```

Can't find the problem
Thank you if you can help me

Comment: Fixed after removing Notifications.setNotificationHandler that was being used in two different files